# Detection of outdated replicas at mysql router

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlrouter

I am using `mysqlrouter` to route traffic to InnoDB cluster nodes with master-slave replication (1 master + 2 slaves). For some reason, I am frequently facing replication issues and seeing that replicas don't have data for the last 2 hours.
As a result, application, which uses Read-Only nodes has incorrect data. Is it possible for mysqlrouter to detect replicas, which are not in-sync and not to route traffic there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that MySQL Router as such option. MySQL Router is more focused in Group Replication.

Maybe you could consider tuning up your replication to reduce the delay.

But if you need such functionality you can look up for [ProxySQL](https://proxysql.com/). It is an alternative to MySQL Router.
You can read more about the functionality in their [documentation](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/MySQL-Server-Configuration#automatically-shunning-slaves-with-replication-lag).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so mysql router has anything to do with replication:

[image]